# getTypeFace from a character

Tags: android, android-studio

Formatted text appears in a edittext.But the string contains multiple styling .

Is it possible to get the styling used on a particular character in a string , using getTypeFace command.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is how to you set that styling?

1. If your doing something like Html.fromHtml("**hello**") calling getTypeFace() will return 0 (TypeFace.NORMAL). For this I would say that you might need to make the parse yourself and create substrings according to the HTML tags you've found.
2. If you your using the TextView attributes for this - android:textStyle="bold"

You can call directly:

```
Log.d(TAG, "has typeface=${tv_typeface.typeface.style}")
```

3. Alternatively if you're using *SpannableStrings* to edit how your text should look

You can do something like:

```
//Set an italic style to the word "hello"
val spannableString = SpannableString("hello world")
spannableString.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
tv_typeface.text = spannableString

//Get the style italic used
val spannedString = tv_typeface.text as SpannedString
val spans = spannedString.getSpans(0, tv_typeface.length(), StyleSpan::class.java)

for (span in spans) {
  Log.d(TAG, "StyleSpan between: ${spannedString.getSpanStart(span)} and ${spannedString.getSpanEnd(span)} with style ${span.style}")
}
```